# Ecipse.ini file dash(-) usage

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to understand the *eclipse.ini* file though I understand the purpose of the tags and their values. However I am concerned about the usage of dash being used in every line differently.

Hence this query:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize (2 dash at the beginning of line)

256M

-showsplash (Only 1 dash at the beginning of the line)

org.eclipse.platform
```

Is any line a commented line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these are comments, it is just that some options start with a single dash and others with two dashes (generally the --launcher.xxx options).

The available options are listed [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)